# Can Intel Xeon Phi improve ffmpeg performance?

Tags: linux, cpu, ffmpeg, encoding

I'm building a server for video encoding and I'm planning to use the latest Xeon e5-2697 v2.

Can `Xeon Phi` help me improve ffmpeg encoding performance?

a bit confused by this new "processor" http://ark.intel.com/products/family/71840/Intel-Xeon-Phi-Coprocessors/server

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be a custom version of ffmpeg built specifically for the Xeon Phi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much investigation it apears I've two options:

1) Running generic application straightly on it. You can ssh to the
coprocessor and do whatever you need in its internal Linux.
2) Using computation distribution technologies like MPI, OpenMP or NUMA.

But as for now ffmpeg does not leverage any of MPI, OpenMP and NUMA.

Comment: Did you manage to build ffmpeg for the Xeon Phi?